# How to modify split function to split string

Tags: asp.net

Please help me to split string with "," having "desc,a" as single item in result.

```
string s="\"desc,a\",True,True,False,True,0,1,red,1,1,"
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `r = s.SubString(0,8)` or did you mean something diferent?

Comment: No i want to save string in an array by s.Split(',');  method but it returns 12 items in array.i want to split it in a way that \"desc,a\" become 1 item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to match items with and without quotation marks:

```
string[] items =
  Regex.Matches(s, @"""[^""]*""|[^,]+")
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(x => x.Value)
  .ToArray();
```

Explanation:

```
""[^""]*"" - matches an item with quotation marks
             (quot, zero or more non-quot character, quot)
|          - or operator
[^,]+      - matches an item without quotation marks
             (one or more characters other than comma)
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to take a look at regular expressions:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx